# execute a procedure my_proc() inside my POSTGRESQL database using Task Scheduler

Tags: postgresql, procedure, job-scheduling

I have to schedule a procedure to run on daily basis in postgresql using windows task scheduler.

I have created a job it is running but not fetching data.

Where do i exactly mention my procedure.

I didn't understand exactly where do I need to mention this cmd  given in the link

```
psql -U username -d databasename -w -c 'SELECT my_procedure()'
```

[steps for task scheduler](https://sqlbackupandftp.com/blog/postgresql-job-scheduler)

Comment: You can't `select` from a procedure - do you mean a function?

Comment: This given in the link I mentioned. Even I also didn't understood exactly. Any help is appreciated

Comment: @ASHUTOSHKumar could you perhaps elaborate a bit more on your use case? Where do you need to save the function output?

Comment: Actually we have created a procedure which will truncate and load the data in table everyday at certain time period. Right now we r doing manually but trying to schedule through task scheduler